# Unable to create object methods and assign object's value in the same statement

Tags: javascript

case 1: The following code explains how Ii can create methods and assign values to a object

```
var obj = function(){return 0}; // obj is asigned with a function object
obj.val = obj(); // val property is created and assigned with a value
```

now I was able to do this by writing 2 statements but JS doesn't allow me to write this definition of object in single statement like case2.

case 2:

```
var obj = {function(){return 0}, val : obj()};
```

case 3: people might suggest that i can write it this way

```
var obj = { 
            func : function(){return 0},
            val : obj.func()
          };
```

but i dont want to write it this way becoz both are properties and none are values. i want the object behavior to be that of case 1 and code written like case 2.

can anybody throw some light on how this can be achieved in JS

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? What is the desired outcome?

Comment: @RichardDalton i can have a default value to an object instead refering it with a property like func
i want the methods of an object to access the value of an object without using the property created to store the value

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what it is you want to achieve, but you could do either of the following:

**Create and instantiate the object directly**

```
var obj = {
  val: 0
};
```

**Use an invoked function to return the desired object**

```
var object = (function() {
  var self = {};
  self.val = 0;
  return self;
})();
```

Both suggestion essentially do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function in the format of case 1:

```
function defaultValueObject(obj) {
    obj.val = obj();
    return obj;
}

var x = defaultValueObject(function () { return 0; });
```

... but I really don't understand why you are trying to do this..

Answer (score 0):

Underscore or jQuery may help. For example

```
var composed = _.extend(function(){return 42}, {val: 10})
composed() // 42
composed.val // 13
```